# Is there any way to get torch.mode over multidimensional tensor

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, pytorch

is there any way torch.mode can be applied over multiple dimensions

for example

```
import numpy as np
import torch
x = np.random.randint(10, size=(3, 5))
y = torch.tensor(x)
```

lets say y has

```
[[6 3 7 3 0]
 [2 5 7 9 7]
 [6 1 4 6 3]]
```

`torch.mode` should return a size 3 tensor `[3,7,6]`

without using a loop

Comment: If you use `torch.mode` on your example, you get what you want. Can you provide another example?

Answer (score 1):

Use the dimension attribute in torch to select which dimension should be reduced using mode operator.

```
torch.mode(y, dim = 1)[0]
```

Will give you the desired answer.